# ¿Cómo extraer el contenido de un tag <script> con php?

Tags: php, html, script

Como puedo extraer de una pagina html el contenido de "file" o "sources" de un tag `<script>` el cual está así:

```html
<div class="show_div" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="video" style="margin:0px auto;" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
    <div id="standout" style="margin:0 auto; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; position:relative; z-index:40;">
      <div id="home_video"></div>
      <script>
        var secs = 0;
        var lastp = 0;
        var runc = 0;
        jwplayer.key = "; var playerInstance = jwplayer("
        home_video ").setup({"
        autostart ": false,"
        controls ": true,"
        flashplayer ": " / jwplayer7 / jwplayer.flash.swf ","
        image ": "
        https ": //700FFVQAUKB92L3IVDQB6.jpg", ga: {}, "mute": false, "ph": 1, "preload": "none", "primary": "html", "repeat": false, "skin": {
        "name": "tu"
        }, "stagevideo": true, "stretching": "uniform", "visualplaylist": true, "width": "100%", "aspectratio": "16:9", "provider": 'http', "startparam": "start", tracks: [{
        "file": "",
        "kind": "thumbnails"
        }], "sources": [{"file": "Dato que requiero","label": "480p"}, 
        {"file": "Dato que requiero","label": "720p"}, "Dato que requiero"], 
        "logo": {
        "logoBar": "",
        "target": "blank",
        "link": ""
        }, "displaydescription": false, "displaytitle": false, "abouttext": "", "aboutlink": ""
        });
        playerInstance.on('ready', function() {
          jwLogoBar.addLogo(playerInstance);
        });
        playerInstance.on('time', function(event) {
          if (runc === 0) {
            var time = Math.floor(event.position);
            if (time > lastp + 10) {
              if (lastp != time) {
                lastp = time;
                $.getJSON("/?c=l&i=FFVQ9XIBKA&o=3807c0ff49a4b8d7d9cd9ae6b415857e&a=" + canRunAds, function(data) {
                  if (data.status == 1) {
                    runc = 1;
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          }
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El tag no tiene "id" o "class", pero es el único que cuenta con la palabra "visualplaylist" en toda la página e intenté hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```html
<?php
include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html( $url ); 
$file = $html->find('script');
 foreach ($file as $vid) {
  if(strpos ($v->innertext, 'visualplaylist') !== false) {
   $script = $vid;
  }
 }

print_r($script);

?>
```

Este no funciona (no cuento con mucho conocimiento) ¿Podrían ayudarme? Gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes probar con expresiones regulares:

```
$html = "CONTENIDO HTML DONDE SE ENCUENTRA LA ETIQUETA SCRIPT";
$regex = '#\<script(.*)>((.|\n)*)</script>#';
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
```

Ejemplo:

```
$html = "

<h1>Título</h1>
<p>párrafo</p>
<script>

    var x = 1,
        y = 2;

    function sum(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }

    sum(x, y);

</script>";

$regex = '#\<script(.*)>((.|\n)*)</script>#';
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);

print_r($matches); //imprime el resultado que se encuentra en $matches
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

    var x = 1,
        y = 2;

    function sum(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }

    sum(x, y);


        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

        )

)
```

Como puedes ver, el contenido de la etiqueta script se encuentra en:

```
$matches[2][0];
```

Después de obtener los contenidos de las etiquetas script, puedes recorrerlos buscando la cadena 'visualplaylist' para localizar el contenido que buscas.